# Exporting signed apk for different architectures

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, platform, android-multiple-apk

I have a native library that my project uses(for four architectures). (Note, that I did not compile them , I just got them from a third-party). Exporting a signed apk right now is a pain. I do the following:

1. Delete 3 of the 4 architectures from the libs folder
2. Export a signed package
3. Replace the libs folder with history
4. Go back to step one

Now, these steps are fairly tiresome and there is a chance of making mistakes while uploading.

Is there any simple way I can just Export 4 apks for the for 4 different architectures (in an automated way)?

I am using Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Well done for considering the user, and producing architecture specific apks, rather than bundling all architectures in a single apk with the resultant waste of filespace on already constrained devices.

Eclipse (or rather the ADT) does not have the ability to do what you want.

One answer to your problem (unfortunately adopted by many developers) is to simply give up, and just produce one apk with all architectures included.  (I've even seen this happen for system apps - that by definition must know exactly what architecture they are going to run on).

An approach I've taken is to export the app from Eclipse with all architectures in it, and then to manipulate that apk using a zip tool to produce further copies with the unwanted libs deleted.  You then have to resign the apk since you have changed the constituent contents.

Comment: What I have done right now works. I compile the app after deleting the unnecessary libraries.